# sbt continuous compilation broken

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using continuos compilation with my sbt project but all of the sudden I'm getting this error

```
~compile
[error] (client/compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Error occurred obtaining files to watch.  Terminating continuous execution...
```

Looking at the source, I see that sbt is getting an exception and it terminates

[Watched.scala](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.0.x/main/command/src/main/scala/sbt/Watched.scala)

Is there a way to extract the original exception and solve this error?

Comment: run the command `last`

Comment: Did you ever solve this?